# Conditionally evaluate heading using knitr in .Rmd file

Tags: r, knitr

Is it possible to conditionally evaluate a code chunk **and** its associated heading using R Markdown and `knitr`? For example, if `eval_cell` is `TRUE` include the chunk **and** its heading, but don't include either if `eval_cell` is `FALSE`.

````
```{r}
eval_cell = TRUE
```

# Heading (would like to eval only if eval_cell is TRUE)
```{r eval = eval_cell}
summary(cars)
```
````

Comment: **If** it's not supported, then first `brew` a document with `<% ... %>` tags, or give a try to my [pander package](http://rapporter.github.io/pander/#brew-to-pandoc).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can put the heading in an inline R expression:

````
```{r}
eval_cell = TRUE
```

`r if (eval_cell) '# Heading (would like to eval only if eval_cell is TRUE)'`

```{r eval = eval_cell}
summary(cars)
```
````

This will become cumbersome if you have large blocks of text/code that need to be conditionally included, in which case you are recommended to put them in a separate child document, say, `child.Rmd`:

````
# Heading (would like to eval only if eval_cell is TRUE)
```{r}
summary(cars)
```
````

Then in the original (parent) document, you just need

````
```{r}
eval_cell = TRUE
```

```{r child='child.Rmd', eval=eval_cell}
```
````