# Excluding part of the R markdown (html_notebook) from the final html output

Tags: r, r-markdown, rnotebook

I am writing a relatively long report using R Notebook that makes use of R markdown language which combines text and code in the same document and generates html output.

I would like to be able to exclude some of the analysis (both text and R code) from showing in the final HTML. This is very useful if I want to create two versions of the report - a full/detailed version, as well as a shorter version with main graphs and conclusions.

Obviously, I can create separate Rmd file for each type of report (or comment out pieces of the report that need to be excluded for the shorter version), but I was wondering if there is a more elegant way to do it.

Something like this:

````
     if (Version == "full_text"){

                Full analysis goes here 

                ```{r}
                R code goes here (could be multiple chunks)
                ```
     }
     else {
                The shorter version goes here 
                ```{r}
                R code goes here 
                ```
    }
````

Comment: Place the lengthy part in a [knitr child document](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/inst/examples/child/knitr-main.Rmd) which you call based on a condition. This is explained in this question: [conditionally include a list of child documents in RMarkdown with knitr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39377465/conditionally-include-a-list-of-child-documents-in-rmarkdown-with-knitr)

Comment: See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32958018/2641825)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the "detailed" part of the report in a [knitr child document](https://yihui.name/knitr/demo/child/#using-chunk-option-child-for-markdown-rmd-documents) which you call optionally from the main document. 
Detailed content can then be switched on by calling the child document and it can be switched off by setting the variable `child_docs` to `NULL`. For example here are a main and a child document below.

## Child document

Save this document under `knitr-child.Rmd`

````
---
title: "knitr child"
output: html_document
---

# Details from the child document
Hi, there. I'm a child with a plot and as many details as necessary.

```{r test-child}
plot(cars)
```
````

## Main document - full/detailed version

````
---
title: "Report"
output: html_document
---

# Summary 

```{r setup}
child_docs <- c('knitr-child.Rmd')
# child_docs <- NULL
```

```{r test-main, child = child_docs}
```

# Conclusion
````

[image: full version]

## Main document shorter version

````
---
title: "Report"
output: html_document
---

# Summary 

```{r setup}
# child_docs <- c('knitr-child.Rmd')
child_docs <- NULL
```

```{r test-main, child = child_docs}
```

# Conclusion
````

[image: shorter version]